# Prestashop - Orders showing no date

Tags: php, prestashop, orders

Just wish to start I'm not great with Prestashop and been forced to ask here since my question on their support fourms has gone unanswered for 3 months.

I'm trying to help a site owner that runs a Prestashop site on "PrestaShop™ 1.4.6.2" using a Barclay card payment for taken payments. This has the affect that orders no longer show dates. I'm unsure how to debug this or resolve so I'm hopeful someone can aid in pointing in the correct direction so I can understand this more and resolve this.

I can see that the order dates and times are showing correctly in the database so unsure why the order page isn't pulling the information from the database

Thanks in advance

More information:
As requested from the comments the Database is correctly storing the dates of the order.

Comment: You'll need to find out more before anyone can help. First thing, check your DB tables. Is the date being added to your order tables?

Comment: The Database does have the invoice_date adding dates correctly

Comment: Okay, so the payment module isn't stopping table inserts, which is good. Next, where precisely do you mean when you say they aren't displaying? Front-office? Back-office? Which page?

Comment: It's in the back office when looking at the orders overview and the detail orders. Normally it says "Status" "Dates" and "PDF". Status and PDFs have information down the columns but Dates don't.

Comment: Still can't find the reason for this or how to move forward.

Comment: It sounds as if the issue is caused by the payment module. Is the module third party? If that's the case, you will need to contact them rather than PrestaShop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience there are many significant changes made to each new version of Prestashop, PHP, and Barclaycard's integration platform that could all impact upon the correct working behaviour of the module introducing bugs or compatibility issues unless the module is maintained and software updates made available to you.

Have you upgraded your Prestashop version or PHP version recently? If so, do you have a working backup you could return to or compare with?

Since this is a commercial software product your first port of call should always be to contact the original software vendor for support. There will likely be contact details for the original developers written into the top of source code files or in an accompanying *readme.txt* file.

You'll be unable to post the source code online in a public forum and so it's unlikely we'll be able to help beyond signposting you to the options available, so with that in mind here are some of the options available to you in the event you are unable to reach the original vendor:

- Paid programming support from a web development or hosting company that specialise in PHP development and have experience writing code for and supporting Prestashop installations.
- The payment module you currently use for your Barclaycard ePDQ integration will unlikely be the only one available, since add-ons such as this are not usually very expensive you could try a different module from a different software vendor. A google search for "prestashop epdq" should quickly reveal the relevant modules available, though Barclaycard also list a couple of [Prestashop software integration partners](http://www.barclaycard.co.uk/business/accepting-payments/e-commerce-services-for-sme/ePDQ-integration#OP) on their website.